# Есть ли ошибки в пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация

Я отвечаю таким игрокам, чтобы они для начала успокоились и хотя бы на пару дней сделали перерыв – а кроме того, завели бы блокнотик и написали мне через пару дней.

Comment: А какая связь между блокнотиком и "написали мне"?

Answer (score 1):

Я **говорю** таким игрокам, чтобы они для начала успокоились и хотя бы на пару дней сделали перерыв, – а кроме того, завели бы блокнотик и написали мне через пару дней.

1) **Отвечаю, чтобы** - не очень подходит для изъяснительного придаточного;

2) Можно использовать **запятую и тире как единый знак**, который разделит предложение на два блока.